# Javascript (React + Flow) - Destructuring with nullable nested objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype, destructuring

I'm trying to destruct an object that can be null at a moment.
For example with the following :

```
const { dolphin } = this.props.route.params;
```

I want **dolphin** to return *null* if **route** or **params** is *null*.

But whatever i try, i always got the exception "Cannot read property 'dolphin' of undefined.

Can anyone as a tip for this please ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest you're going to get with a one-line destructuring assignment is this:

```js
const { dolphin } = this.props.route?.params || { dolphin: null };
```

But it doesn't return `null` only if `.route` or `.params` is `null`; it does so if they are any falsy value.

Comment: And what if i have multiple const ? Like dolphin, squirrel, etc...
Can i have a one-line destructuring assignment ?

Comment: Yes, just separate them with commas.

Answer (score 2):

Using [nullish coalesce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator), [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining), and [default value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Default_values):

```js
function test(x) {
  this.props = x;
  const { dolphin = null, whale = null } = this.props.route?.params ?? {};
  return { dolphin, whale };
}

console.log(test({
  route: {
    params: null
  }
}))

console.log(test({
  route: null
}))


console.log(test({
  route: { params: { dolphin: 1, whale: 2 } }
}))
```

Please make sure to note the compatibility table at the bottom for browsers.  If you are using babel you should be okay.  Since you are using React and Flow, you are probably already using browser targeted transpilation with Babel, so it shouldn't be an issue.